# Determining Java Azure IoT Hub DeviceClient connection state?

Tags: java, azure-iot-hub

Is there a way to determine if the client is/isn't connected using the client SDK?  I see how to do that using the JavaScript and .NET SDKS, but I don't see anything similar in the Java version of DeviceClient.  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean [connectionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-identity-properties)? It can be accessed using service SDK not the client SDK. How did you do that?

Comment: I'm looking for something on the *client* side, not service-side.  The client itself needs to know when it's connected to the hub, and when it's lost connection, that way we can start buffering data instead of trying to push it up to IoT hub.

Comment: I mean there is no connection state defined in [DeviceClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient?view=azuredevicesclient-1.2.6).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT there is actually, it's just in a protected field, which is the problem.  Is there some other way that I'm missing that I can determine whether or not a DeviceClient is actually connected?  I've also noticed that open doesn't actually throw an exception if you specify an invalid device ID and/or symmetric key.  It just continually tries to reconnect in the background. That makes it even more difficult to determine if the DeviceClient is actually connected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java SDK, but as I know Java SDK does not support event trigger.

I'm afraid you have to check connection state before sending data as official SDK does https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/master/device/iot-device-client/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/device/DeviceClient.java#L250

Also, Java SDK use loop to receive messages, but not MQTT subscription https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/master/device/iot-device-client/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/device/DeviceClient.java#L197

So maybe you need to handle a schedule to check state as well.

Comment: The state field is protected, and the DeviceClient itself is final, so I can't extend it in order to grab the state.  Is there some other way to get at the state that I'm overlooking?

Comment: I read the code again, and I find it seems state only updates in open, initIotHubClient and close, so we cannot detect connection state depends on state even if we can read it. I'll ask other colleagues on Monday and post updates I get.

Answer (score 0):

In Java SDK, when you send event, it will be pushed to a waiting list. There is a thread to consume and send message in this list.

I tried to close the network connection when the device is sending messages per second. Since there's a lock on the waiting list, so the consuming thread will be stuck. The message will retain in the waiting list. After the connection is  recovered, message in the waiting list will be sent.

There isn't a way to get the status of the waiting list. Maybe here's a work-around for you requirement, you can maintain a processing counter. When you send message, increment the counter, and meanwhile you register a callback which will decrement the counter. You can check the counter to proximately "guess" the connection state.